# Sequelize migration foreign key name

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js, sequelize-cli

I am trying to set a name on my foreign key. In my migration my code look like this:

```
"tb_acl_grupos_id": {
            "type": Sequelize.INTEGER(11),
            "field": "tb_acl_grupos_id",
            "references": {
                "model": "tb_acl_grupos",
                "key": "id"
            },
            "defaultValue": "1",
            "allowNull": false
        },
```

I read about

> belongsTo

but i do not understand very well... Can i use belongsTo on migration?
Or it is possible to set using another way?

Comment: belongsTo is used in model definition, your code above should already set up foreign key with `references`

Comment: @feiiiiii, thank you for the clarification!
But there is any way to declare the foreign key name in my migration?

Comment: you already did it. the above code should set `CONSTRAINT constriaintname  FOREIGN KEY (tb_acl_grupos_id) REFERENCES tb_acl_grupos  (id)` when you run the migration, which means `tb_acl_grupos_id` is declared foreign key because you used the `references` attribute.  so if you need to set another one just use `reference`

Answer (score 0):

I have found others needs for my project, such as procedures and trigger. The best way to configure every thing, was to create separete files for every table / function / trigger / stored procedure and then call this files on my migration file. because of this separation I could use `migration.sequelize.query` to create my foreign keys / triggers / stored procedures and function. The way @feiiiiii sayed works, but in this way sequelize generate my foreign key with a certain pattern.